# Ссылка в слове TextView

Tags: android, textview

хочу что бы при нажатии на слово в textview меня переносило на другую активити,такое можно реализовать?Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Можно. Например через `ClickableSpan`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте через Spannable:

```
SpannableString ss = new SpannableString("Android is a Software stack");
ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
@Override
public void onClick(View textView) {
    startActivity(new Intent(MyActivity.this, NextActivity.class));
}
@Override
public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
    super.updateDrawState(ds);
    ds.setUnderlineText(false);
}
};
ss.setSpan(clickableSpan, 22, 27, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
textView.setText(ss);
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
textView.setHighlightColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

И в Xml:

```
<TextView 
  ...
  android:textColorLink="@drawable/your_selector"
/>
```